# Junit test for email service

Tags: java, spring-boot, email, junit, jakarta-mail

I want to test a simple method that sends email using smtp.gmail.com. The person who is sending email and the password is set at the application.properties and is being used using @Value annotation. How could I write the Junit test for such a method?

I have tried using fake smtp and green mail. But I don't understand how it works and how the are implementing. I am using gradle. I have included the fake smtp in build.gradle but don't know how to change the location where the email will be send.

This is my Junit test class:

```
 import static org.junit.Assert.*;

 import javax.mail.MessagingException;
 import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;

 import org.junit.Test;

 import com.Email.EmailServiceApplication;

 public class EmailServiceTest {

    @Test
    public void test() throws AddressException, MessagingException {

        EmailServiceApplication esa = new EmailServiceApplication();
        assertEquals(esa.sendEmail("abhi", 1), "Email sent successfully");
    }

}
```

This is my Method:

```
private void sendmail(EmailMessage emailmessage, int ver) throws AddressException, MessagingException {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com");     
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");     
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    // get session for email
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, 
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                }           
    });

    if(ver == 1) {
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username, false));
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(emailmessage.getTo_address()));
        msg.setSubject("Job uploaded");
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart.setText("job has been uploaded successfully!");        
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        // Set text message part
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
        // Send the complete message parts
        msg.setContent(multipart);
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());
        // Send
        Transport.send(msg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in its current state your code is difficult to test as the setup of the email provider and the sendlogic are in the same method. This makes it impossible to send emails to another location than smtp.gmail.com.

I'd suggest to split both aspects into some smaller methods. This makes it possible to pass in e.g. a greenmail mail provider.

Something like:

```
Session createMailSession() {
    ... your original session creation logic here
    return session;
}

void doSendMail(Session session, EmailMessage emailMessage, int ver) {
    if(ver == 1) {
        ... your original sending logic here
    }
}

public void sendMail(EmailMessage emailmessage, int ver) {
  doSendMail(getSession(), emailMessage, ver);
}
```

Now you can test the sending logic with a different email provider e.g. greenmail:

```
@Test
public void canSendMail() {
   Session testSession = greenMail.getSmtp().createSession()
   doSendMail(testSession, ..., ...)
   assertEquals(1, greenMail.getReceivedMessages().length)
}
```

Comment: I have posted my answer following the changes and it works well!